# Overlapping with flat-top window MATLAB

Tags: fft, window

I am applying a flat-top window to signal because I am very interested in its actual amplitude in the time-domain. I have read that overlapping will improve results. I am using MATLAB and the following is the code that I am using to compute FFT with flat-top window:

```
time = 0:0.1:500;  
data = 1.8*sin(2*pi*0.2003*time);Fs = 10;  
N = length(data);  
w = flattopwin(N);  
wdata = data(:).*w;  
ws = sum(w);  
Y = fft(wdata)/ws;  
freq = 0:Fs/N:Fs/2-Fs/N;  
freq = freq';  
amplitude = 2*abs(Y(1:floor(N/2)));  
plot(freq,amplitude);
```

Can someone please help me to modify the code so that I can include overlapping? I am relatively new in this field and am still confused. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Higher size of your FFT best the resolution of frequencies, but of course it has a cost resulting in a longer to process !

To apply overlap you need define one window size to analyse and one hop/step to walk around your data!

This picture illustrates how this works:

[image]

Here a simple code using Window size = 2048pts and 50% overlap step!

```
n_samples = length(yourdata);
winSize = 2048;

%50% overlap or 0 to not use overlap
OverlapStep = 50;

if OverlapStep > 0

    Overlap = floor((OverlapStep*winSize) / 100); 
    nFrames=floor(n_samples/Overlap)-1; 
else
    Overlap= winSize;
    nFrames=floor(n_samples/Overlap)-1;
end


k=1;
while ( (k+winSize-1) <= n_samples )

    FrameSignal = yourdata(k:k+winSize-1);

    %%%%%%%%%% Start process FFT here  %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    w = flattopwin(winSize);  
    wdata = FrameSignal(:).*w;
    Y = fft(wdata)
    .
    .
    .

   k=k+Overlap;
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I used your code with winSize = 84240 and 50% overlap. The original data file had 421200 data points. Thus, the code has calculated 9 ffts. When adopting the overlapping method, can I average the 9 amplitudes to get a single amplitude and corresponding frequency?

Comment: I am currently looking at a similar problem. I am trying to use overlapping method for the first time in Matlab in order to get better accuracy of the amplitude of my signal. Using the Matlab code shared above, I have been getting error 'Index exceeds matrix dimensions' for the calculation of the magnitude. How to resolve this issue?